# Google SDK/gcloud, cannot upload files because of SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Google Compute Engine, installed Google SDK on Windows 8.1

I get the following message when trying to upload a text file from my Windwos laptop to my VM instance.

```
c:\Users\user\Desktop>gcloud compute copy-files test.txt root@<my instance>:<my folder> --zone <zone>
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) [C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\sdk\scp.EXE] exited with return code [1].
```

I've googled (yeah ...) the mesage and got an explanation saying: "This means that the public key generated by your SSH client was successfully transferred to the server but did not match the one stored on the server."

I'm not very skilled on SSH-related stuff and knowing that the SSH terminal launched via the web Google Developers Console works fine, I didn't want to mess up with the SSH config files on the VM side.

Thank you in advance for your support

BR

Comment: I was able to do it transferring a file from a Windows instance to a Debian instance. What image are you using? Could you check if you see this line :`PermitRootLogin yes` in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file? If not, you'll need to modify it and restart the SSH server (`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart)

Answer (score 2):

First I've done some SSH cleanup following the "Setting up ssh keys" section in the following GCE page [Google Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console). On my laptop I've generated **SSH-2 RSA** keys using Puttygen, added the public key following **Compute->Compute Engine->Metadata** then in **SSH tab**, then succesfully connected to my VM via Putty (adding the private key .PPK file in the Putty window) using my "user_name_gmail_com" user already defined during VM instance creation.

Once I've understood that I started looking at the existing public and private keys generated by the SDK in C:\Users\user\.ssh folder. I could also connect to the VM with the private key via Putty using the same user name.

OK, once the SSH stuff understood, I've launched the `copy-files` as above and now got a `permission denied`. I solved this by simply adding the "~" before the remote folder name

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>gcloud compute copy-files test.txt <user_name>_gmail_com@<my instance>:~/my_folder --zone <zone>
test.txt                  | 0 kB |   0.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```